# Why is my function to find the smallest word in an array not working?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I am writing a program to print out the smallest word in phrase. The output is supposed to give me the word "I" but it is instead printing out the word "am". How can I fix this? Please help, I am new to Python

```
#Given a string 'phrase' consisting of some words separated
# by some number of spaces, return the
# smallest word in the string.

def word_length(phrase):
    splitphrase = phrase.split(" ")

    min_word = ''
    for i, element in enumerate(splitphrase):
        if i < len(splitphrase)-1 and (len(element) <= len((splitphrase[i+1]))):
            min_word = element
    print(min_word)



word_length("hello I am Sam and am tall")
```

Comment: Why do you check `len(element) <= len((splitphrase[i+1]))`? Can you explain how this is supposed to help you in finding the shortest word?

Comment: `result = min(phrase.split(), key=len)` btw

Comment: Hint: `"am"` is the last word in the string that is shorter than the next word.

Comment: Hint: Notice the program is to capture the shortest word, min_word.  The algorithm never stores a current minimum word and evaluates if another word is shorter and should replace the current min_word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll put my code down below and then explain the changes I made:

```
def word_length(phrase):
    splitphrase = phrase.split(" ")

    min_word = splitphrase[0] #setting default value as first word
    for element in (splitphrase): #for each word in the list
        if len(element) < len(min_word): #if the word is shorter than our current min_word
            min_word = element #redefine min_word if the current word is shorter
    print(min_word)



word_length("hello I am Sam and am tall")
```

Output:

```
I
```

Similar to your code, we start by using the `split()` function to break our sentence up into words in a list.

To start finding the smallest word, we can define our `min_word` to initially be `splitphrase[0]` as our default value.

To determine if other words in the list are `min_word`, while iterating through every word in the list, if the length of the word we are iterating through in our list is less than the length of current `min_word`, we redefine `min_word` to be that current element.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any further help or clarification!

Comment: thank you so much, this was a beautiful response. I appreciate it thank you!!

Comment: no problem!! ty for the compliment :))

Comment: @hershey10 Does my response completely answer your question? You haven't accepted any of the answers yet so I was just wondering if you needed me to add/clarify anything

Answer (score 1):

This code, just checks each word if its length if less than the previous shortest words length.

```
def word_length(phrase):
    splitphrase = phrase.split(" ") # Split the phrase into each individual word

    min_word = splitphrase[0] # Store the shortest word we've found yet
    for element in splitphrase: # Iterate over every word
        if len(element) < len(min_word): # Check if we haven't already set the min_word or this word is smaller than the current min_word
            min_word = element # Set min_word to the new shortest word

    print(min_word)

word_length('Hello how is it going today') # > is
```

Comment: Even after correcting the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, this prints nothing. Please check that your code is working before posting it.

Comment: When i copied the code the colon after the if apparently didn't come with.

Comment: Use of *enumerate* seems unnecessary here

Comment: You might have updated it, but you probably didn't test it, as `word_length("I am not working")` just prints an empty string. We expect answers to be working and valid, so please *don't* post code before you have tested it. SO is neither a guessing game nor a speed contest...

Answer (score 1):

How about like this:

```
def word_length(phrase):
    sw = (words := phrase.split())[0]
    for word in words[1:]:
        if len(word) < len(sw):
            sw = word
    return sw
print(word_length("hello I am Sam and am tall"))
```

**Note:**

This will fail if *phrase* is an empty string or None. You will also need Python 3.8+

Answer (score 1):

1. the maximum word length possible is the length of the sentence
2. I check that each word is smaller than the maximum length
3. if it is smaller I reassign the value of min_word and the min_word_length

```
def word_length(phrase):
    splitphrase = phrase.split(" ")

    max_word_lenght = len(phrase)
    for el in splitphrase:
        if len(el) <= max_word_lenght:
            max_word_lenght = len(el)
            min_word = el
    print(min_word)



word_length("hello I am Sam and am tall")
```

If you are new to python I would recommend learning a debugging tool so you can better understand the flow of your program.
If you use the command line a possibility is PDB (https://realpython.com/python-debugging-pdb/).

If you use IDE (Spyder, VS, PyTorch) they should have a debugger built-in